# ColdFusion Hash Value Not Changing

Tags: coldfusion

Take the following code...

```
<cfset thisToken = createUUID()>
<cflock scope="SESSION" type="EXCLUSIVE" timeout="10">
    <cfif not isDefined("session.allTokens")><cfset session.allTokens = ""></cfif>
    <cfset session.allTokens = ListAppend(session.allTokens, thisToken)>
</cflock>

<cfoutput>
    #thisToken#
    <br><br>
    #hash(thisToken, "SHA-512")#
    <br><br>
    #session.allTokens#
</cfoutput>

.... a few html lines, nothing special ....

<input type="hidden" name="token" value="#hash(thisToken, "SHA-512")#">
```

If I run this page in multiple browser tabs, the first tab works fine, but in all other tabs after that the hash in the hidden (when viewing source) does not equal the hash in the cfouput right above it.  It's strange, the hash in the cfoutput displays a new unique UUID for all tabs but the hidden always contains the same value in tabs 2, 3, 4, 5, .....

Why is the hash in the hidden not unique and matching the hash in the cfoutput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what's up now.  For some reason, in Chrome, "view source" isn't always showing the proper source for the tab.  Not sure why.  But if I do "Inspect Element" instead and view the hidden that way it does in fact contain the correct unique value in each tab.  Must be some issue with Chrome when viewing source when multiple tabs have the same URL but slightly different content.